# How to create an extended toolbar in Android with an EditText at the bottom

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am trying to create a toolbar in **Android** that is **2x** in height of the normal toolbar, and has an `EditText` in the lower half portion.

Currently, I have the XML code (note the `android:layout_height="128dp"`):

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:title="Messages"
            android:titleTextColor="@color/windowBackground"
            android:background="@color/buttonBackground"
            android:layout_height="128dp"      
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="bottom" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/no_activity_fragment"
            class="com.ohmd.ohmd.ui.main.MainActivityListFragment"
            android:name="com.ohmd.ohmd.ui.main.MainActivityListFragment"
            android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what it looks like (with no `EditText` yet):
[image]

So a few problems that I'm stuck on:

- **(a)** How can I get the "Messages" to align to the top where it does when the height is set to `"?android:attr/actionBarSize"`?
- **(b)** Aftter moving the title up, how can I add an `EditText` view in the lower half?

This is what I am hoping to acheive:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it with:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:title="Messages"
        android:titleTextColor="@color/windowBackground"
        android:background="@color/buttonBackground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/buttonBackground"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

            <EditText
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/tvSection"
                android:background="@color/buttonBackgroundSelected"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could try changing the toolbar gravity to

```
android:gravity="top"
```

If that doesn't work, you could get rid of the "title" and add a TextView to the toolbar like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="128dp"
    android:background="@color/buttonBackground"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:titleTextColor="@color/windowBackground"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:text="Messages"
        android:textColor="@color/buttonBackground"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```